# Chrome doesn't declare my JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

There's problem when I test my code on Google Chrome and I don't have any problem when test it on Firefox.
I've a function and I call it in `onblur` event.
It's working fine on Firefox but Google Chrome gave me this error on the console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: fill is not defined

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="mytitle" onblur='fill(this);'>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function fill(element,value = false){
    if(element.value == ""){
        $("#"+element.id).css('border-color','red');
    }else{
        $("#"+element.id).css('border-color','#56de56');
    }
    if(value == true){
        if(element.value > 75 || element.value < 5)
            $("#"+element.id).css('border-color','red');
    }
}
```

and I declared `fill` function before that line and after that line so I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EcmaScript, the standard JS is based on as of version 5.1 does not support optional parameters.

```
function fill(element,value = false){
```

Does not do what you expect it to. Instead, you have to do this manually:

```
function fill(element,value){
     if(typeof value === 'undefined') {
          value = false;
     }
```

Or in a shorter notion if you're only expecting boolean values

```
function fill(element,value){
    value = value || false;
```

Note - These both have cases they miss - as  Fabrício Matté suggested in the comments you can also check `arguments.length` if you want to differenciate not getting an argument passed, and getting `undefined` explicitly although that's rarely the case.

<sup>although optional parameters are in the EcmaScript 6 proposal</sup>

(Firefox however, [does independently support them even today](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters))

Comment: You meant the ECMAScript 5.1 spec I believe.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté right you are, mixed up what I thought about and what I wrote - started writing "You can't do optional parameters in JavaScript yet" and changed my mind. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum really !! .. ok i will test it without optional parameter

Comment: @YahiaSweid-BillGates It's one of those cases where Firefox developers at mozilla eagerly implemented a language feature that made it through to the ECMAScript 6 draft :)

Comment: You can also use `if (arguments.length < 2)`, in the rare case when passing `undefined` as the `value` argument must be treated differently from omitting the argument.

Comment: I don't think it's obvious to everyone but there is no sense in debating the actual code since one should define a function and then just call that like `value = optional(value, false);` or whatever. DRYYYYyyyy